# How to get selected text using android spinner wheel?

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-wheel

I am using [Android Spinner Wheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) and I already set code for that.

```
AbstractWheel wheelHorizontalView1 = (AbstractWheel) findViewById(R.id.wheelHorizontalView1);
NumericWheelAdapter minAdapter = new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 1, 15,"%01d");
minAdapter.setItemResource(R.layout.wheel_text_centered_dark_back);
minAdapter.setItemTextResource(R.id.text);
wheelHorizontalView1.setViewAdapter(minAdapter);
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: spinner wheel image]

So, my question is how to get 3 as my selected text ?

Here is xml if needed,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:background="#007704" />

    <com.spinnerwheel.WheelHorizontalView
        android:id="@+id/wheelHorizontalView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        app:selectionDivider="@android:color/white"
        app:selectionDividerWidth="2dp"
        app:visibleItems="6" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out which item is selected?  Because you say "how to get 3 as my selected text ?", but 3 is already selected, so I'm thinking what you mean is "how do I determine what is selected?"

Comment: look like want to get selected text as question says "How to get selected text ...."

Comment: Yes, I want to get text of selected text, whatever field comes in green square after scrolling.

Comment: How did you set a green background on the selected item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `setCurrentItem(int index)` function:

```
wheelHorizontalView1.setCurrentItem(2);
```

If you want to know when the user changed the value
you have to implement this listener.

```
    wheelHorizontalView1.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    ...
    ...  
    // Wheel changed listener
    private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
        public void onChanged(AbstractWheel wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
            // newValue is the currently selected item
        }
    };
```

Comment: How do I get index, after whatever codes written above in my question?
and if it says setCurrentItem(index) where do it calls to getCurrentItem().

Comment: more here: https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel/blob/master/demo/src/antistatic/spinnerwheel/demo/ProgrammaticSwitchingActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found in demo to get value.

```
value=getWheel(viewId).getCurrentItem();
```

Method

```
   private AbstractWheel getWheel(int id) {
        return (AbstractWheel) findViewById(id);
    }
```

**Or**

```
value=wheelHorizontalView1.getCurrentItem();
```

Comment: Any Particular Listener is there in which, I can call

 Toast.makeText(this, wheelHorizontalView.getCurrentItem()+1 + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Because it calls only once, on create. I want it dynamic.